# Instalando MySql no linux de maneira programática. Como setar o password?

Tags: linux, bash

Estou criando um arquivo sh para iniciar um ambiente de programação no Linux para automatizar esse processo de inicialização.
Normalmente só rodo as seguintes linhas de comando e durante o processo de instalação do MySql tenho que escolher a senha do usuário ROOT.

Esse é o código:

```
//Iniciar sessão como super usuário para não escrever senha todo o tempo.
sudo su #MyPassword#
//Limpar a tela
clear

//Fazer a atualização do apt-get.
apt-get update
//Limpar a tela
clear

//Instalar MySql Server
apt install mysql-server
//Escolher a senha para root. OK
//Limpar a tela
clear
```

Como eu faço para passar a instrução de instalação do mysql e tbm o password do root ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o seu `.sh` e adicione:

```
echo "mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password senha_aqui" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password senha_aqui" | sudo debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.6
```

Há a documentação sobre o [debconf-set-selections](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs03.html) no Ubuntu, que é uma forma de definir e armazenar valores para utilizar em scripts não interativos.

[Fonte¹](https://serversforhackers.com/video/installing-mysql-with-debconf)
[Fonte²](https://gist.github.com/sheikhwaqas/9088872)
[Fonte³](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-password-prompt)